# HTML/JSP Variables

Tags: html, jsp, variables

I am wondering is there anyway to define a variable in HTML/JSP. I googled very hard but couldn't find any resources on this. Basically in my html/jsp I am trying to save an external value into a variable that's specific to the html/jsp, so that I can print this variable to the webpage afterwards. Let's say this external value is 5. Can we do something like

x=5
 ?

T

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
<c:set var="x" value="5"/> 
...
${x}
```

`<c:set>` is a tag from the [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/reference/docs/index.html).